# Simple string replace in Elm?

Tags: string, elm

Is there an easy way to replace a part of a string in Elm? I am interested in plain search without a regex. (And I understand that I can’t change the string, I am happy to get a new one with the changes in place.)

Comment: You may also use [`Native.Regex.escape`](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/master/src/Regex.elm#L35) with Elm regex to make the pattern treated as a literal character sequence.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way I could think of:

```elm
String.split "from" "target string: blah... from ..."
    |> String.join "to"
```

https://runelm.io/c/f07

Answer (score 4):

Current versions of Elm (0.19.0+) include [`String.replace` in elm/core](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/String#replace).

Example:

```
String.replace ":" "" "06:00" == "0600"
```

[Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/74Tfpz2qr8ta1).

Answer (score 3):

I see, the [string-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/string-extra/latest) package offers `replace`.

Comment: I wouldn't trust that package. It is still considered experimental.

Comment: Surely a plain string replace should work fine? It’s implemented as an escaped regex replace.